# Is there a way to change the order that slickgrid displays grouped rows? (Asc, vs Desc)

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Is there a function I can set to a column that when the grid is grouped by that column it will know to sort the getter in a certain order, either ascending or descending for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `comparer` property of the grouping settings object.

Here's a snippet from *example-grouping.html*:

```
function groupByDurationOrderByCount(aggregateCollapsed) {
  dataView.setGrouping({
    getter: "duration",
    formatter: function (g) {
      return "Duration:  " + g.value + "  <span style='color:green'>(" + g.count + " items)</span>";
    },
    comparer: function (a, b) {
      return a.count - b.count;
    },
    aggregators: [
      new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Avg("percentComplete"),
      new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum("cost")
    ],
    aggregateCollapsed: aggregateCollapsed,
    lazyTotalsCalculation: true
  });
}
```

The comparer is passed to the javascript `sort` method. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) for more info about how to construct the comparer function.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. That's pretty cool, looks like you can do a lot more things than just sorting with that!